# Python 3.7.2 Elif not working only if statement

Tags: if-statement, python-3.7

When I print the dictionary `d`, only `white` gets changed into `Mindful`, the rest stay as the color.

```
import random

clrs = ['white', 'blue', 'black', 'purple', 'pink', 'yellow']
d = {}

while True:
    spawn = int(input('enter how many creatures to spawn: '))
    for x in range(spawn):
        clr = random.choice(clrs)
        print (clr)
        if clr=='white':
            clr='Mindful'
        elif clr=='blue':
            clr=='Anima'
        elif clr=='black':
            clr=='Dimension'
        elif clr=='purple':
            clr=='Enigma'
        elif clr=='pink':
            clr=='Light'
        elif clr=='yellow':
            clr=='Golem'
        else:
            print ('wtf how have you done this')
        d["ball{0}".format(x)]=clr
    print (d)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
clr=='Anima'
   ^^
```

Did you think this was going to actually *change* `clr` to something else? I think not :-)

Perhaps `=` may be better here (and it all the other non-white ones as well.

---

See the following transcript for more detail, `==` forms an expression while `=` assigns:

```
>>> xyzzy = 'plugh'
>>> xyzzy == 'twisty' ; print(xyzzy)
False
plugh
>>> xyzzy = 'twisty' ; print(xyzzy)
twisty
```